# C# - How do I get a user input for date and time

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application, user-input

I want to be able to get a point from a database using the date and time the point was created. I want to do this by asking the user what date/time they want and then use that date/time to find the point. This is my code currently, it gets the point but only the data from the exact time I run the code. I would like to be able to get data from a 6/4/2012 4:50:29 for example.

```
//connect to pi server
    PIServers piServers = new PIServers();
         foreach (var server in piServers)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Server: {0}", server.Name);
         }
         PIServer piServer = piServers.DefaultPIServer;
         Console.WriteLine("Default Server: {0}", piServer.Name);

        piServer.Connect();

        //get a PI Point
        var point = PIPoint.FindPIPoint(piServer, "Pipoint");

        var value = point.Snapshot();
        Console.WriteLine("Point {0} Value {1} {2}", point.Name,
        value.Value.ToString(),value.Timestamp.ToString());
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Are you asking how do you get an input datetime from a user and then retrieve a DB record with that input?

Comment: Correct, in this case that DB record will come in the form of an entire column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is first ask the user:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter date");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

Now `userInput` is a string so you need to cast it into a `DateTime` object, I would not cast it directly since it is very easy to get a `InvalidCastException`, so we should use the built in `TryParse(String, out DateTime)` to validate if it is a correct `DateTime`.

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParse(userInput, out result);
```

If `userInput` was a correct `DateTime` then the `result` will be a valid `DateTime` object. If it was not correct the `result` will be `DateTime.MinValue` so I would check:

```
if(!result.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
{
  // Continue to look it up in the DB
}
```

Comment: e.g. `2015-01-01 00:00:00` here are a list of formats https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to get an input from a user and store that value in a variable.

I am assuming `var point = PIPoint.FindPIPoint(piServer, "Pipoint");` is the line of code that queries the DB for a match.

In that case you would want to pass the datetime as a string. `string input = Console.Readline();` and then just pass userInput to the FindPIPoint method.

But if the .FindPiPoint method is looking for a datetime you would need to cast it to a datetime object first.

Since this is working on the assumption that any possible datetime is a possible match(and I doubt this is the case) you should add some error handling for an incorrect match.